# What are the implications of saying 保护好自己?

Tags: meaning, usage, phrase-meaning

I've heard this used in various contexts, but there is one that I am confused about which relates to being emotionally vulnerable. Specifically, it seems like people say that about situations where they might face being emotionally vulnerable and are afraid to standup for themselves or simply express their own feelings, even if other people are not acting maliciously toward them.

Comment: What is the implication of saying "take good care of oneself" (照顧好自己)? You need to be more clear on what you thought it implies.

Comment: something like "保重" as take care, just a polite wish.

Answer (score 2):

保護好自己 is

> "love yourself, take care of yourself, don't give up on yourself, and don't let people hurt you over and over again."

Answer (score 1):

I thought 保护好（你）自己 is more likely to be used when talking to someone going into a dangerous situation, maybe a rescuer entering collapsed buildings after an earthquake.

But I did find:

作为女人要学会保护好自己，尤其是自己的情感问题。
As a woman, you've gotta learn to protect yourself, especially with regard to your emotional well-being.

And this:

说保护好自己，
If someone says 'protect yourself',
一般都是对女人等相对弱势群体来说的。
generally this remark is aimed at women or disadvantaged groups.
这句话应用在男人身上，
Saying this to a man,
有开玩笑的味道。
smacks of jesting.
所以这句话可能是一句玩笑话。
Thus this phrase may be a joke. (when directed at a man.)

Men! No emotions! :)

Answer (score 0):

This sentence implies that the receiver is perceived to be in adverse circumstances, or going to face uncertainties or challenges. The occasions to say it include, but are not limited to, the following:

- Relatives comforting a child who has lost his/her parents to an accident.
- Father/mother giving advice to the child on the first day attending a new school.
- Father/mother saying farewell to enlisted son.
- Kung-fu masters say to each other before carrying out assignments.